# Eclipse RCP retrieve compilation errors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse rcp. When i run a project, it is first builded and then launched. If the builder failed to compile the project, then i have to notify the user about that.

Which is the better way to know if there were errors during compilation?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was contained in the api of [IncrementalProjectBuilder](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IncrementalProjectBuilder.html) in the build method:

> Throws:
>       CoreException - if this build fails.

I have to throw an exception when the builder failed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add your own builder in eclipse. Go to Project->properties->Builders and then New to add your own builder. You can have an ant script or maven as builder. Ofcourse you need to know ant for this.

Comment: The compiler i used is an external program which i run with a custom builder i developed.I'm developing a custom ide where i don't have the builders properties of eclipse